# Selenium: finding element by href

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How would you find an element in selenium (with python) of the following html:

```
<a href="/user/login" onclick="ttweb.UserOperations.Login.OpenLoginPopup({ LoginUrl: '/user/login', RedirectUrl: '/' }); return false;">Login</a>
```

[image: Code]

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button')

Answer (score 2):

As per the HTML you have shared to find the element by `href` you can use either of the following:

1. **`css_selector`**:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href=/user/login]")
   ```
2. **`xpath`**:

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/user/login']")
   ```
3. **`xpath`** (Multiple Attributes):

   ```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/user/login' and text()='Login']")
   ```